# how to manipulate cookie with js

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, session-cookies

here this code just stores te options and atlast it produces the result from adio buttons. i want it inted of radio button use of textbox or input field. so what should be changed?

```js
<script language="JavaScript">
var timer,timecounter=0
function readCookie(name)
{
   var result=null;
   var myCookie=document.cookie+";";
   var searchName=name+"=";
   var start=myCookie.indexOf(searchName);
   var end;
   if(start!=-1)
    {
      start+=searchName.length;
      end=myCookie.indexOf(";",start);
      result=myCookie.substring(start,end);
    }
  return result;      
}
function writeCookie(name)
{
  var expDate=new Date();
  var day=1*24*60*60;
  expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime()+day);
  document.cookie=name+"="+timecounter;
}
function starttimer(counter,ans)
{
var cook 
    timecounter=parseInt(readCookie(<%=chr(34) & examname&"totaltime"& chr(34)%> ))
   var index=-1
   if(ans=="A")
        index=0
   else if(ans=="B")
        index=1      
   else if(ans=="C")
        index=2      
   else if(ans=="D")
        index=3

   if(document.examform.qno.value-1<=counter&&index!=-1)
        document.examform.elements[index].checked=true
      timer=setInterval("change()",1000)

}
function stoptimer()
{
    writeCookie("<%=examname&"totaltime"%>");  
    clearInterval(timer)
}
function change()
{
    var hrs,mins,secs;
    hrs=parseInt(timecounter/3600);
    mins=parseInt(timecounter/60);
    secs=timecounter%60;
    window.status="Time Remaining : "+hrs+":"+mins+":"+secs;
    rem_time.innerText="Time Remaining :"+hrs+":"+mins+":"+secs;
    timecounter--
    if(timecounter==-1)
      {
        store_ans()
        stoptimer()
        document.examform.submit()    

      }           
}
function store_ans()
{
     var elems=document.examform.elements 
     var ans=""
    for(var i=0;i<elems.length;i++)
     if((elems[i].type=="radio"||elems[i].type=="checkbox")&&elems[i].checked)
         ans=ans+elems[i].value    
    document.examform.answer.value=ans
    if(ans=="")
      document.examform.answer.value="Not Attempted"    
    stoptimer()
}       
</script>
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: There are also numerous spelling mistakes.

Comment: This is an example that you find somewhere on internet and ask from us to adjust it to your request - not a question at all. You do not even understand that all this is not asp.net at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.cookie`: **get and set the cookies associated with the current document** [(Mozilla Developer Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

You can manipulate cookies with vanilla JavaScript using the `document.cookie` global.

To store multiple cookies, you have to assign `document.cookie` multiple times, e.g to store `var a = '1'; var b = '2'` you do

```
document.cookie = "a=1";
document.cookie = "b=2";
```

To read the cookie string, simply reference `document.cookie`, e.g `console.log(document.cookie)`

Also, your post has several editing and grammatical mistakes. Additionally, this is a question which can be easily answered with a Google search.